# Abstract Factory Pattern in Java -- issues populating array

Tags: java

I am trying to learn how to use the abstract factory pattern. Here is the situation:

I have a few classes that implement an interface like this :

The class (there are a few different ones):

```
public class AluminiumCasing implements BatteryComponents {

    public String toString() {
        return "Aluminum Casing";
    }

}
```

The interface:

```
public interface BatteryComponents {

    public String toString();

}
```

I have an enum:

```
public enum CarType {
    SOULEV, OPTIMAHYBRID, RIO
}
```

I am trying to fill an array with various battery components in this way :

```
public abstract class CarBattery {
    public BatteryComponents[] parts;
    private CarType model = null;
    private Location location = null;

    public CarBattery(CarType model, Location location) {
        this.model = model;
        this.location = location;
    }

    protected abstract void construct();

    //this is the array i am unable to populate. Once it works, the idea is to fill it with different parts according the model
    public BatteryComponents[] collectParts(CarType model) {
        this.model = model;
        switch (model) {
            case SOULEV :
                // Change made with SO user suggestion. This has not fixed it.
                parts = new BatteryComponents []{ new LithiumCells(), new AluminiumCasing(), new ArduinoController(), new OneTenVCharger()};
                //BatteryComponents parts[] = { new LithiumCells(), new AluminiumCasing(), new ArduinoController(), new OneTenVCharger()};
            break;
        }
        return parts;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        if (parts != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                result.append(parts[i]);
                if (i < parts.length-1) {
                    result.append(", ");
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            result.append("-- not working --");
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

I've created a Battery Factory (BattFactory) like this :

```
public abstract class BattFactory {
    public BatteryComponents[] parts;

    public BattFactory() {

    }

    public static CarBattery buildBattery(CarType type) {
        CarBattery battery = null;
        Location location = null;


        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean validInput;
         do {
            System.out.print("Choose region : 'u' for USA, 'a' for Asia, or 'e' for EU: ");
            char inChar = in.next().toLowerCase().charAt(0); // Convert to lowercase and extract first char
            validInput = true;
            if (inChar == 'u') {
               location = Location.USA;
            } else if (inChar == 'a') {
               location = Location.ASIA;
            } else if (inChar == 'e') {
               location = Location.EU;
            } else {
               System.out.println("   Invalid input, try again...");
               validInput = false;
            }
         } while (!validInput);


        switch(location) {
            case USA :
                battery = USABattFactory.buildBattery(type);
            break;
            case ASIA :
                battery = AsiaBattFactory.buildBattery(type);
            break;
            case EU :
                battery = EUBattFactory.buildBattery(type);
        }
     return battery;
    }
}
```

Here is USABattFactory:

```
public class USABattFactory extends BattFactory {
    //public String carModel;
    public BatteryComponents[] parts;

    public static CarBattery buildBattery(CarType model) {
        CarBattery car = null;
        switch (model) {
            case SOULEV :
            car = new SoulevCarBattery(Location.USA);
            break;

            case OPTIMAHYBRID :
            car = new OptimaHybridCarBattery(Location.USA);
            break;

            case RIO :
            car = new RioCarBattery(Location.USA);

            default:
            break;
        }
        return car;
    }
}
```

I extended the Battery Factory to create a particular type of battery:

```
public class SoulevCarBattery extends CarBattery {
    public BatteryComponents[] parts;

    public SoulevCarBattery(Location location){
        super(CarType.SOULEV, location);
        construct();
    }

    @Override
    protected void construct() {
        System.out.println("Building Soulev car battery");
    }

}
```

When I test my code, I realize that my array was never populated and is null:

```
public class TestBattery {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(BattFactory.buildBattery(CarType.SOULEV));

    }

}
```

The result:

```
Choose region : 'u' for USA, 'a' for Asia, or 'e' for EU: u
Building Soulev car battery
-- not working --
```

**UPDATE**:

My attempt to integrate collectParts() includes some restructuring of CarBattery and the classes that inherit from it. It is now working.

```
public class SoulevCarBattery extends CarBattery {
    public BatteryComponents[] parts;

    public SoulevCarBattery(Location location){
        super(CarType.SOULEV, location);
        construct();
        collectParts(location);
    }

    public BatteryComponents[] collectParts(Location location) {
        switch (location) {
            case USA :
                parts = new BatteryComponents []{ new LithiumCells(), new AluminiumCasing(), new ArduinoController(), new OneTenVCharger()};
                //BatteryComponents parts[] = { new LithiumCells(), new AluminiumCasing(), new ArduinoController(), new OneTenVCharger()};
            break;
        }

        return parts;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        if (parts != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                result.append(parts[i]);
                if (i < parts.length-1) {
                    result.append(", ");
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            result.append("-- not working --");
        }


        return result.toString();
        //return model + " car battery built in " + location + result.toString();
    }


    @Override
    protected void construct() {
        System.out.println("Building Soulev car battery");
    }

}
```

Comment: Note: your `BatteryComponents.toString()` method overrides `Object.toString()`. You don't actually need to declare it explicitly in the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always returning empty array

Change

```
 BatteryComponents parts[] = {new LithiumCells(), new AluminiumCasing(), new ArduinoController(), new OneTenVCharger()};
```

to this

```
parts = new BatteryComponents []{new LithiumCells(), new AluminiumCasing(), new ArduinoController(), new OneTenVCharger()};
```

Comment: I just tried what you suggested and unfortunately i'm still getting "--not working--"

Comment: Where is your CarBattery.buildBattery() code?,
You don't seem to be calling collectParts anywhere...

Comment: I have it in BattFactory

Comment: Can you post class USABattFactory here

Comment: You are not calling collectParts method anywhere in the code so your parts array is not initialized yet, causing this error.
Also you need not to declare public BatteryComponents[] parts; in child class

Comment: okay--how silly. i got quite confused. what do you think is the best way to work it in?